# WSO2 - OAuth2/token is throwing the 405 error

Tags: wso2

As part of project learning, I m trying to access WSO2 API Manager. I downloaded the WSO2-AM-2.5.0. As my PC is already equipped with java. I havent installed.
I started services with "bin/wso2server.bat".

Once it is started i am trying to access carbon and logged in with admin/admin credentials. Once i am logged in i created Tenant in configure module and created tenant successfully.

Once Tenant is created. I jumped into store URL and logged in with the selected Tenant credentials and created an application with that Tenant. Once Application is created. I tried to generate Client Id and Secret key.
I copied those details, i have API https://localhost:9443/oauth1/token for generating Access_Token. But unfortunately didnt worked with Windows 10 (64Bit) and Linux Ubuntu 16.04 version.

Please guide me where i m doing wrong with this approach. 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in wso2carbon.log? I guess you are getting this error when you hit the generate keys button in the application.

Comment: @Ayyappa: Please show us a screenshot of the request you're sending. Also, please use this url to generate tokens. `https://localhost:8243/token`

Comment: @Bee Please find the attached screenshots of my tests. i tried with http then thrown SSL error and kept https back and tried. still no use.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Your explanation says the URL has `oauth1` in it, and the screenshot shows it has `oauth2` in it. But in the error response I can see the correct URL as `https://localhost:8243/token`. Which one is the correct one? `Question 2`: please confirm you didn't change any files in `repository/deployment` directory.

Comment: Oauth1 is typo mistake.oauth2/token is copied from /carbon. You please tell me which one is correct and yes i didnt change anything in the directory. Finally with CURL i can test the https://localhost:8243/token with grant_type=client_credentials. and it given me the {"access_token":"4b10af9c-3bd2-37a3-a691-f40a303ae641","scope":"am_application_scope default","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600}.  using git bash not with postman.

Comment: In wso2 apim default pack, the token endpoint will be localhost:8243/token .
In wso2 is default pack the token endpoint will be localhost:9443/oauth2/token

Comment: It worked with http://localhost:8280/token at RestClient. Thanks for helping @senthalan. Now, the task is trace down the forgot password API for created Tenant Credentials and for other custom roles with email functionality.

Comment: @Bee Ok. Now i m trying to import all the available SOAP services at SOAPUI https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl but throwing some error. WSDLException (at /html): faultCode=INVALID_WSDL: Expected element '{http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/}definitions'. Even Service is running under wso2am-2.5.0 version